# I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong with this regex, it's suposed to match everything between id":" and "

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to match the "83eec6e44ea04dee9103e845ad51c4f0" from this json, but I'm getting an error (shown below). I got the json from a httpget request btw. From reading the error myself it looks like it has something to do with the httpget but I'm getting the data from the request just fine.

```
username = message.content;
var request = require('request');
request(`https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/${username}`, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
// body is this: body = {"name":"uhWillem","id":"83eec6e44ea04dee9103e845ad51c4f0"};
        console.log(body)
        message.channel.send(body);
        regex = "(?<=id\":\")(.*)(?=\")";
        match = body.match(regex);

        message.channel.send(match)
    }
})
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\wille\OneDrive\Bureaublad\discordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298
     throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
           ^

DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
   at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\wille\OneDrive\Bureaublad\discordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
   at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\wille\OneDrive\Bureaublad\discordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
   at async TextChannel.send (C:\Users\wille\OneDrive\Bureaublad\discordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:172:15) {
 method: 'post',
 path: '/channels/883457777035534417/messages',
 code: 50006,
 httpStatus: 400,
 requestData: {
   json: {
     content: undefined,
     tts: false,
     nonce: undefined,
     embeds: undefined,
     components: undefined,
     username: undefined,
     avatar_url: undefined,
     allowed_mentions: undefined,
     flags: undefined,
     message_reference: undefined,
     attachments: undefined,
     sticker_ids: undefined
   },
   files: []
 }
}
```

Comment: Why exactly are you attempting to parse JSON with RegExp? Just serialize it to an object and refer to it with dot notation; any other method (especially in JavaScript) is quite ill-advised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to parse your JSON. It is simpler and probably faster for more complex JSON.

```
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  let { id } = JSON.parse(body);
  message.channel.send(id);
}
```

If you need to use regexp, you need to know that `.match(regex)` returns an array, therefor you should only choose the first element:

```
matches = body.match(regex); // Don't name it match... It's an array :)
message.channel.send(matches[0]);
```

But a much more performant code can be used! You can stringify the text before the id key (we know the name key == username) and `.substring()`:

```
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  let pre = `{"name":"${username}","id":"`;
  // id is 32 characters long (16 bytes)
  let id = body.substring(pre.length, pre.length+32);
  message.channel.send(id);
}
```

If you want to use the id outside the `request` callback, you need to wrap everything in a promise and a dedicated function:

```
const request = require('request');



function get_username_id(username) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => request(
    `https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/${username}`,
    function(error, response, body) {

        if (error || response.statusCode != 200) reject(error || response.statusCode)

        // body is {"name":"uhWillem","id":"83eec6e44ea04dee9103e845ad51c4f0"};
        resolve(JSON.response(body));

    });
}



let username = message.content;
get_username_id(username)
.then(({name, id}) => {

    console.log(`The id of ${name} is ${id}`); // here we should see the name == username and the id

    // here we work with the data, eg we send it
    message.channel.send(id);

    // you can return a promise that resolves to something else and chain it with an other .then()
    return Promise.resolve('This will be recived after the first promise');

})
.then(text => {
    console.log(text);
    // id and name are not accessible anymore, but you can pass them on...
})
.catch(err => console.error(err)); // here we print the error or status code different from 200
```

This is quite longer and more complex but allows being more flexible in the development for the future.

I suggest you take a look around, SO to find more information about promises.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the information I needed by parsing it, but I was wondering how I can use this information outside of the request, because outside of the function it returns 'id is not defined'  how would I carry the information over to a new HTTP request?

Comment: @Willem I edited my answer to explain in an extensive way how to wrap your code in a promise and in a function. Promises are a really important thing to get to know in JS, so I suggest learning them properly before proceeding to add more features.

Answer (score 0):

The `body` contains JSON, and if you want to extract the id, just use

`const match = JSON.parse(body).id`